# How to join tables to get rows by city?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem. So I have two tables - Location and Journey as follows:

```
Location
--------
town
city 
country


Journey
-------
TransportType
Cost
Class
From
To
Distance
TimeTaken

<From> and <To> in Journey table are foreign keys linked to <town> in Location table.
```

I want to be able view all locations by city when the journey is in the same city ie both towns `<From> and <To>` are in the same city. I can't figure out the sql to join the tables!!

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Here is some random data. As I mentioned I want to do the query to list only those journeys where towns are in the same city. For example the first journey (bet Hearst and Kearney) or the third journey should be listed but not the second one as the latter is between two different cities. –

```
town,city,country
Hearst, Ontario, Canada
Kearney, Ontario, Canada
Grimsby, Ontario, Canada
LaSalle, Ontario, Canada
Kirkland Lake, Ontario, Canada
Gore Bay, Ontario, Canada
Corktown, Toronto, Canada
Quayside, Toronto, Canada
Casa Loma, Toronto, Canada
Rosedale, Toronto, Canada
ByWard Market, Ottawa, Canada
Centretown, Ottawa, Canada
Centretown West, Ottawa, Canada
Downtown, Ottawa, Canada
The Glebe, Ottawa, Canada
Golden Triangle, Ottawa, Canada

TransportType,Cost,Class,From,To,Distance,TimeTaken
0, 32.45, A, Hearst, Kearney, 45, 55
0, 15.25, B, Hearst, Quayside, 125, 100
0, 75.15, A, Corktown, Rosedale, 215, 210
0, 45.45, A, Rosedale, Quayside, 105, 110
0, 245.30, A, Downtown, LaSalle, 312, 324
1, 245.80, A, Gore Bay, Centretown, 252, 374
2, 115.10, A, Grimsby, Kirkland Lake, 145, 95
2, 115.10, A, Grimsby, Golden Triangle, 145, 95
2, 268.20, B, Gore Bay, Centretown, 347. 40
1, 184.40, A, LaSalle, Quayside, 642, 39
2, 422.50, A, Downtown, Kearney, 239, 83
1, 97.20, B, Centretown, Gore Bay, 68, 93
2, 185.60, B, Grimsby, Rosedale, 281, 413
2, 463.50, B, Kirkland Lake, Casa Loma, 98, 83
1, 338.20, B, Hearst, ByWard Market, 34, 54
2, 79.70, A, Corktown, The Glebe, 437, 521
1, 224.50, A, Kearney, Centretown West, 43, 29
1, 395.90, B, Rosedale, LaSalle, 543, 685
1, 45.40, A, Downtown, Kirkland Lake, 68, 73
2, 255.60, B, Gore Bay, Quayside, 32, 21
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output for the sample data as well.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. To help us understand your question better, please provide a [mcve]. See also: [Why should I provide an mcve for what seems to me to be a very simple sql query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: You question format is confusing and you have not posted it in table format. Remove comma and post same as it stored data in Sql server table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the 2 tables using `Location.town` 
to match both `Journey.From` and `Journey.To`:

```
select tfrom.* from 
(select j.*, loc.city from Journey j
inner join Location loc
on loc.town = j.FromTown) tfrom
inner join
(select j.*, loc.city from Journey j
inner join Location loc
on loc.town = j.ToTown) tto
on tto.city = tfrom.city 
and (tfrom.FromTown = tto.FromTown and tfrom.ToTown = tto.ToTown)
```

and another simpler way:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM (Journey as j INNER JOIN Location as fromLoc ON j.FromTown = fromLoc.Town) 
INNER JOIN Location AS toLoc ON j.ToTown = toLoc.Town
WHERE fromLoc.City = toLoc.City;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8fcb77fcd56f97513f928c037ea2ed91)

Comment: hey forpas - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately in your answer, the join is to the same town so I get NO rows. Its like saying I have a journey going from Grimsby to Grimsby. As you can see from the second table, there aren't any journeys such as this in the same town.

Comment: In your question: *<From> and <To> in Journey table are foreign keys linked to <town> in Location table.* Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes that is correct. That's why I'm having a problem trying to get the right query. I need all the journeys in the same state and not in the same town! For example, in my data for table 2 above, I have a journey between Hearst and Kearney which are in the same state, Ontario so the query I need should pick up this journey for the Ontario state. But your query won't pick them up because it would be only be looking for Hearst to Hearst  or Kearney to Kearney. Hope that explains the problem.

Comment: Your query is similar to the following I already tried which doesn't unfortunately work:
  select Location.*, Journey.* 
from Location, Journey 
where Journey.From = Location.town and Journey.To = Location.town 
order by Location.state

Comment: See my edited answer. I changed the names of From and To columns to FromTown and ToTown.

Comment: If the combination `FromTown` and `ToTown` is not unique in table `Journey` then maybe there will be needed more conditions in the final join.

Comment: Thank-you forpas.

Comment: @HotChocolate did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: Apologies forpas - I missed hitting the tick. Thank-you for taking the time to check the queries on the test platform.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show all cities where in-city journeys occured.

You must join the location twice to get from from-town / to-town to from-city / to-city. Keep all records where from-city equals to-city. Then show the thus found cities only once with `DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct from_loc.city, from_loc.country
from journey
join location from_loc on from_loc.town = journey.[from]
join location to_loc on to_loc.town = journey.[to]
where from_loc.city = to_loc.city;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten - exactly what I was looking for!